# Prepopulate a huge production DB

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, h2

I am developing a Spring Boot application that stores song lyrics. I am using the H2 database and am initializing the test DB using the data.sql file. But when this goes into production, will this approach be scalable for say 1000s of songs? Whenever the server starts, all the songs need to be inserted into the in-memory DB from a single data.sql file. Let's ignore the server-bootup time for now.

Note that there will not be any write operations from the application. That is, no one can upload a song to the application. They can only search and view the songs that already exist.

How is this done conventionally? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to seed your datastore each time you startup your application ?

Comment: I think your question is more suitable for the [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) community, as it seems to be the general concern.